# Why is $I = \left \{ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i | a_0 \in 2 \mathbb{Z} \right \} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ not a principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Why is $I = \left \{ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i | a_0 \in 2 \mathbb{Z} \right \} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ not a principal ideal?

We saw it as a short example for a non-principal ideal in a linear algebra course, I have no knowledge in abstract algebra.

But I think every polynom can be written as $2 *p(x)$ for some $p$ so I'd expect it to be principal, what am I missing?

I barely understand the language of this field so a basic answer would be best.

Comment: $2+x$ is in the first ideal but not in the ideal you describe

Comment: Every polynomial can not be written as $2p(x)$ as you claim. Take for example the monomial $x$. In fact, $I=(2, x)$, the ideal generated by $2$ and $x$ (prove this). Now, why can't there be a single element generating $(2,x)$?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing that $x\in I$ as well as $2\in I$. There is no single generator that gives both without also giving $1\in I$.

Comment: Thanks, how would one formally prove this? generally speaking

Comment: @paxtibimarce A principal generator must be a common divisor ($2\in (a)$ means exactly that $2$ is a multiple of $a$, or that $a$ is a divisor of $2$). The divisors of $x$ are $\pm x, \pm 1$ and the divisors of $2$ are $\pm 2,\pm 1$. The only common divisors are $\pm 1$, but $I\neq(1)$.